# View submit passes null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this button in my view:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreatePageDetails","Secure", new { id=item.id })</td>
```

I pass it to this controller:

```
public ActionResult CreatePageDetails(string id)
        {
            var model = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>();

            return View(model);
        }
```

I must be missing something because when i put a beakpoint at the controller it shows null as parameter. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Secure" is a wrong parameter for the `Object routeValues`.

Comment: "Secure" is the name of my controller.

Comment: Stupid question, but is the item.id null?

Comment: Be sure you are using the right overload for ActionLink, there are so many that accept various objects I've had the problem of accidentally using the wrong method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreatePageDetails","Secure", new { id=item.id }, null)
```

if you use intellisense to look at the overload [you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), that 4th parameter is the htmlAttributes.  The [one you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) takes 5 parameters, the 4th being the routeValues.

Actually, since you are able to reach you controller from your code, you don't need to specify it, and can use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreatePageDetails", new { id=item.id })
```

Comment: From my memory routeValues is the 4th and htmlAttributes is the 5th?